# Как прокинуть порты между 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 linux

Tags: linux, сеть

Как можно прокинуть друг на друга порты 127.0.0.1:4444 127.0.0.2:4444 в Linux ubuntu

У меня на адресе 127.0.0.1:4444 Живет докер контейнер с selenium-chrome
А на адресе 127.0.0.2:4444 запускаются тесты которые ссылаются только на 127.0.0.1:4444
Как мне ссылать запросы с 127.0.0.1:4444 на 127.0.0.2:4444

Comment: Оба контейнера объединить с помощью докер-композа?

Comment: Возможно ли это, если один из них gitlab-runner?
Есть ссылка подробная на это?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/450312/